# Large number of concurrent ajax calls and ways to deal with it

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, concurrency

I have a web page which, upon loading, needs to do a lot of JSON fetches from the server to populate various things dynamically. In particular, it updates parts of a large-ish data structure from which I derive a graphical representation of the data.

So it works great in Chrome; however, Safari and Firefox appear to suffer somewhat. Upon the querying of the numerous JSON requests, the browsers become sluggish and unusable. I am under the assumption that this is due to the rather expensive iteration of said data structure. Is this a valid assumption?

How can I mitigate this *without* changing the query language so that it's a single fetch?

I was thinking of applying a queue that could limit the number of concurrent Ajax queries (and hence also limit the number of concurrent updates to the data structure)... Any thoughts? Useful pointers? Other suggestions?

Comment: Can you cache the responses based on the request?

Comment: @Tim: no, only the server really knows whether the data is new (or the cache is old) or not. having said that i did wonder if i should try to house a local database on the client side. (but then i'd have to fiddle with cache invalidity etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In browser-side JS, create a wrapper around jQuery.post() (or whichever method you are using)
that appends the requests to a queue.
Also create a function 'queue_send' that will actually call jQuery.post() passing the entire queue structure.

On server create a proxy function called 'queue_receive' that replays the JSON to your server interfaces as though it came from the browser, collects the results into a single response, sends back to browser.
Browser-side queue_send_success() (success handler for queue_send) must decode this response and populate your data structure.

With this, you should be able to reduce your initialization traffic to one actual request, and maybe consolidate some other requests on your website as well.

Comment: +1 This is also much kinder to the network, as the ratio of HTTP-headers:JSON-data is horrible with lots of small JSON requests.

Comment: thanks; this was the idea i had too; but figured someone musta already created it... and it was: [jquery.ba-jqmq.js](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-message-queuing/docs/files/jquery-ba-jqmq-js.html) :) seems to work quite well too!

Answer (score 0):

> in particular, it updates parts of a largish data structure from which i derive a graphical representation of the data.

I'd try:

- Queuing responses as they come in, then update the structure once
- Hiding the representation invisible until the responses are in

[Magicianeer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877394/large-number-of-concurrent-ajax-calls-and-ways-to-deal-with-it/5877593#5877593) is also good - but I'm not sure if it fits your definition of "*without* changing the query language so that it's a single fetch" - it would avoid re-engineering existing logic.

Comment: good idea with queuing the responses :) i'll give that a try too. the display itself needs to be dynamic (otherwise i would have just one large single query), so i'll probably invest some effort to have a timer trigger bulk updates on the client end. cheers!

Comment: No ideas what's going on with _my_ typing atm, "hiding invisible"... tsk